# "having an idea" vs. "having a belief"

Tags: synonyms

Do "having an idea" and "having a belief" *strictly* mean the same thing?

I've never encountered "having an idea" in the context of theoretical beliefs, i. e. how things are.

Comment: While I don't care to put modern English in the mouths of 19th-century philosophers, I will content myself with noting that the idioms _having an idea_ and _having a belief_ mean pretty much the same thing, although in general _idea_ and _belief_ don't mean the same thing. It's the _have_ in the idiom that forces it. Constructions are much more important than word meanings.

Comment: There are certainly overlapping meanings of *idea* and *belief*, but as John Lawler says they are used in different contexts. Note that philosophers often use words in non-standard ways or try to argue novel or non-standard interpretations of things (e.g. the relationship between different types of thought/idea/belief.) You're better looking in a dictionary to find meanings and usages than trying to infer it from Peirce or James. *Idea* is obviously not exactly the same word as *belief*, so you will have to be more precise about the context in which you want to use it.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking. If you want to know how the meanings of *idea* and *belief* have changed over time, then the OED is your best bet. If you want to know if *idea* and *belief* can be used as synonyms or the difference in meaning, it's best to ask w.r.t. a particular context rather than ask "what do these words mean in every imaginable context?" If you're asking specifically about the meaning of the word in "They had some strange (ideas|beliefs) about parenting", then that's a valid question but make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: 'Have an idea' is often used punctively. "We'll never get the digger out of this ditch.... ... ... No, wait! I've just had an idea!" (= _have a brainwave_). 'Have a belief' is of course never used punctively.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes, that's one important difference. Also "I have the belief that I can do it" works but "I have the idea that I can do it" not.